# Digital Vibration sensor on NodeMCU ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

First Post.

I'm using a NodeMCU esp8266 connected to a digital vibration sensor. My project is to detect when a pager vibrates to then trigger through the maker channel of ifttt an outcome.

I'm following this project as my base, hoping to adapt it ever so slightly, but the more I adapt the code the less it seems to work. https://blog.erindachtler.me/tutorial-a-wifi-enabled-washing-machine/

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "wifissid"
#define WIFI_KEY "wifikey"

#define NOTIFY_URL 
"https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/myproject/with/key/mykey"

int vibration = 16; //vibration sensor   
int LedPin =4; //built in led
int numberofshouts = 0;
int vibrationstate = 0;
int lastvibrationstate = 0;

void setup() {
pinMode(vibration, INPUT);
pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);

// Connect to WiFi network
Serial.println();
Serial.println();
Serial.print("Connecting to ");
Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);

WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_KEY);

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(500);
Serial.print(".");
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("WiFi connected");

// Start the server
Serial.println("Server started");

// Print the IP address
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

} 


void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int vibrationvalue = digitalRead(vibration);

if (vibrationvalue == HIGH)  {
  Serial.print("Vibration");
  sendDoneNotification();
}

else {
digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);
}

}

void sendDoneNotification() {
WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_KEY);

while((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)) {
delay(100);
}

HTTPClient http;
http.begin(NOTIFY_URL);
int httpCode = http.GET();
if(httpCode > 0) {
// HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

// file found at server
if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
  String payload = http.getString();
  Serial.println(payload);
}
} else {
  Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", 
http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
}
http.end();

 WiFi.disconnect();
 }
```

What happens is my serial just reports

[HTTP] GET... failed, error: connection refused

I don't quite get the post commands. 
I basically want it to read the vibration sensor and while it's reporting no movement do nothing, but after it detects vibration for a couple of seconds it then sends the post command to the maker url that will trigger my ifttt command, thus notifying me on my phone etc.

I have created and run a serial print program to test the sensor and adjust the sensitivity so I know the sensor is working.
My NodeMCU doesn't have a D1 pin so i have it connected to D0, not sure if this is correct or not.

Any tips or advice if there is an easier way of doing this.

Many thanks and have a nice day.

Adrian.